# JSF Pages : encoding into template vs encoding into page?

Tags: jsf, encoding, utf-8, xhtml, iso-8859-1

Which one prevails between :

The encoding declared into the template : `<f:view ... encoding="UTF-8">`

And the one declared into the page : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>`

In other words : my page (having that template) will be encoded in "UTF-8" or in "ISO-8859-1" ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Can't you just test it? Put in a word like "résumé" and see what comes out. Anyway, my gut feeling says the xml declaration will always take precedence, since it's on top.

Comment: @MrLister Thank you for the answer, but when I test a word like "résumé" it's not relevant because both encodings support the accent characters